# Community Cloud Vs. Community Cloud "Starter"

Tags: community, customer-community, enterprise

I am reviewing the Editions and Pricing Pages for [Service Cloud](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/service-cloud/), and under the heading: *Empowering customers with self-service communities*, there is a sub-heading: *Community Starter* that is listed as a feature of the *Lightning Enterprise* license.

I see *Customer Community* and *Customer Account Portal* are listed as available for additional fees, which I'm assuming refers to licensing to *Community Cloud*.

[image: Service Cloud - Community Starter]

I am wondering what the difference is between *Community Starter* and the features available as part of one of the options under *[Community Cloud](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/community-cloud/)*? Take for example licensing *Community Cloud* for a *Self-Service Customer Community* edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Community Starter" refers to the ability for Enterprise, Performance,
>   and Unlimited orgs to create up to 100 un-authenticated sites using
>   Lightning Community Templates.  For these un-authenticated sites,
>   communities licenses are not required.  This allows orgs to publish
>   public pages or knowledge centers (though a separate license is
>   required to author knowledge articles).

More info is available in the Winter '18 release notes: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_networks_communities_wo_licenses.htm